# Using a scala generic class in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have this in scala:

```
object Tester {
  def apply[T : Manifest](description: String, initValue: T) = new Tester[T](description, initValue)
  implicit def TesterToValue[T](j: Tester[T]): T = j.value
}

class Tester[T : Manifest](someData: String, initValue: T) {
  private var value = initValue
  def getValue : T = value
}
```

which allows me to do

```
val t1 = JmxValue("some data", 4)
```

I'm trying to create an instance of this is java, so far I've had no luck
I've tried:

```
Tester t1 = Tester<Integer>("data", 0);
Tester<Integer> t1 = Tester<Integer>("data", 0);
Tester t1 = Tester("data", 0);
Tester t1 = new Tester<Integer>("data", 0);
Tester<Integer> t1 = new Tester<Integer>("data", 0);
```

Is there some limitation in using scala generic classes in java? Or am I just doing something horribly wrong

Comment: For starters, you can strike all of the attempts that don't use `new`. `Tester t1 = Tester<Integer>("data", 0);` isn't syntactically valid Java under any circumstance (that doesn't even have anything to do with Scala).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Tester` class actually has an implicit parameter (because of the `[T : Manifest]` type boundary. The syntax you use is sugar for

```
// Scala Class
class Tester[T](someData: String, initValue: T)(implicit man: Manifest[T]){...}
```

When that gets compiled, the two argument lists are condensed to one, so you end up with the java equivalent of

```
//Java Constructor
public Tester(String someData, T initValue, Manifest<T> man){...}
```

You can see the type signature by running the [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) command on the `Tester.class` file that gets generated by the scala compiler.

So if you are trying to use the `Tester` class from Java, you have to explicitly figure out the parameter that scala's compiler would normally figure out for you.

Looking at the scaladocs, it looks like [ManifestFactory](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$) is where you need to go to create Manifest instances. So your java code would look something like

```
Manifest<Integer> man = ManifestFactory$.MODULE$.classType(Integer.class);
Tester<Integer> tester = new Tester<Integer>("data", 123, man);
```

Comment: I edited my answer a little while ago. The example I added should answer that question.

Comment: I will trust that this will work, but upon further investigation this requires latest version of scala?

Comment: I think in older versions of Scala there was a `Manifest` companion object that had factory methods for Manifests. Poke around in the docs  to find what you need.